# Java - writing to url not working

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to make a java program that changes a text document on my website. The permissions are on that everyone can edit it. I've tried, and reading it works perfectly, but writing doesn't.
Here's the code for the writing:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL infoThing = new URL("http://www.[name of my website]/infoThing.txt");
        URLConnection con = infoThing.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        out.write("Change to this.");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how web apps work, in general.

Comment: Google docs makes it look easy, but collaborative editing is pretty complicated.

Comment: if you want to dynamically change what is on a webpage, you need to use javascript.

Comment: Incorrect, sunrize920. Java does it too. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Answer (score 0):

For a Java program to interact with a server-side process it simply must be able to write to a URL, thus providing data to the server. It can do this by following these steps:

> 1 Create a URL.
>
> 2 Retrieve the URLConnection object.
>
> 3 Set output capability on the URLConnection.
>
> 4 Open a connection to the resource.
>
> 5 Get an output stream from the connection.
>
> 6 Write to the output stream.
>
> 7 Close the output stream.

If you want to write to the url. You have to use the concepts above and concepts for servlets.
An example program that runs the backwards script over the network through a URLConnection:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ReverseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length != 1) {
                System.err.println("Usage:  java ReverseTest string_to_reverse");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            String stringToReverse = URLEncoder.encode(args[0]);

            URL url = new URL("http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/backwards");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            PrintStream outStream = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outStream.println("string=" + stringToReverse);
            outStream.close();

            DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            inStream.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + me);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3877416 The code you wrote is not url writer.. I am just showing you how to write a correct write url code. I have provided and link. Where you can learn about it. And you should accept my answer :P

Comment: If you read my code, and you read the code on the site, you will find that, aside from the reversing, the reading, and variable names, the two are the same. I'm looking for why it wouldn't work; if I try the code from the oracle site, it still doesn't work.